# How do enable debug() logging for modules used in my RN project?

Tags: react-native

I'm using React-Native 0.33.

Lots of modules I depend on have debug logs, which use the NPM debug() module. They require an ENV var to be set, i,e. "export DEBUG=*" to enable the logs.

React-Native doesn't really allow setting ENV vars. I've tried doing process.env.DEBUG='*' in code, and it doesn't work.

How do you guys enable debug logging for modules you depend on in RN?

Answer (score 0):

At the *very beginning* of your app launch in `index.ios.js` *before* you import any of your modules, you could do something like

```
const debug = require('debug');
debug.enable('*'); // or use specific subkeys
```

This will make sure that that subsequent calls like below will actually generate a debug function that logs something

```
const debug = require('debug')('mykey');
debug('Testing debug works');
```

Comment: Thanks! But I tried this, and it didn't enable logs for the modules I was depending on. That's what I'm after-- how do you enable logs in modules built with NodeJS "debug()" logger, when you're in React-Native? They seem to be looking for ENV vars, but React-Native doesn't have env vars.